# JQuery hover on instafeed.js

Tags: jquery, instafeedjs

I've been working on a Instagram feed for my webpage with instafeed.js (http://instafeedjs.com/).

It works, shows the images and any data I required, but jQuery can't recognize the objects that instafeed.js creates (the ones defined on "template").

```
<body>

    <div id="instafeed"></div>

    <script>
        var userFeed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: '**********',
        accessToken: '*************************',
        resolution: 'standard_resolution',
        template: '<img src="{{image}}"/> <div id="hover"><p>{{caption}}</p></div>'
        });

        userFeed.run();
    </script>

    <script>
        $("#hover").hover(function(){
           $(this).fadeOut(40);
           $(this).fadeIn(80); 
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are some of the issues in your code.

1.hover function will not bind to dynamic created elements.

2.hover is also depreciated inted you need to use `.on()` per the [`.on()` jQuery doc pages](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

3.In your case it is better to use it is better to use `mouseenter` `mouseleave`

Following sample code will help you i had masked the user id and acess-token
you need to replace it.

```js
var userFeed = new Instafeed({
  get: 'user',
  userId: '<enter your user id>',
  accessToken: '<enter acess token>',
  resolution: 'standard_resolution',
  template: '<img src="{{image}}"/> <div class="hover"><p>{{caption}}</p></div>'
});

userFeed.run();

$('body').on("mouseenter", ".hover", function() {
  // hover starts code here
  $(this).fadeOut(40);
});

$('body').on("mouseleave", ".hover", function() {
  // hover ends code here
  $(this).fadeIn(80);
});
```

```html
<div id="instafeed"></div>
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/instafeed.js/1.4.1/instafeed.min.js"></script>
```